# Titanium Alloy: get element (node) by tag- or classname

Tags: find, element, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How can i get an element collection by tagname or classname in alloy? Are there javascript equivalents on a object (I know its not on the controller or $) like `.getElementsByTagName()` and `.getElementsByClassName()`? Or how can i retreive a xml node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this still isn't possible, it wasn't as of November last year anyway:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/appc-ti-alloy/rljWBtMVNPM/zP4JsUbdpYcJ